# Mask border with transparent png?

Tags: html, css

Racking my brain over this and can't come up with a solution.

Conceptually, the thought is to:

- have a div with background image of house and copy
- ::before element for border
- ::after for logo

Problem is the logo masking of the border.

As far as I know this isn't possible. Any ideas (must have decent browser support)?

[image]

Mockup code:

```css
.hero-banner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40vw;
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/Ft1XsIn.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.hero-banner h1 {
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 200px;
}

.hero-banner h1 small {}

.hero-banner::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 70px;
  right: 70px;
  bottom: 70px;
  left: 70px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}

.hero-banner::before {
  content: url('http://www.technozion.org/tz15/assets/mat/images/generic-logo.png');
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 150px;
  height: 122px;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero-banner">
  <h1><small>The Story of</small><br/>This House</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you include your code?. This is possible to do exactly as in the image.   Absolutely position the logo with its container.

Comment: No code at this point, just a concept. Positioning the logo isn't the issue. Issue is the clipping/masking of the border. Just looking for guidance.

Comment: Use three borders and for the top border use a before and after pseudo element.  But as you have no code, your question is too broad therefore off topic for this site

Comment: Mockup code here: https://codepen.io/mcseay/pen/wjbRPy
    <div class="hero-banner"><h1><small>The Story of</small><br/>This House</h1></div>

Comment: Code mockup now included in original question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Try this it's very essay

<div>
 <fieldset>
  <legend align="right"><img src="http://www.technozion.org/tz15/assets/mat/images/generic-logo.png"></legend>
  <p>some text here</p>
 </fieldset>
</div>
<style>
div{padding:30px;background: url(https://i.imgur.com/Ft1XsIn.jpg) no-repeat  center center;
background-size: cover;}

fieldset{border:2px solid #fff;padding:10px;}
legend img{
 width:100px;

}
</style>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/renukaSingh/g1n6ugyq/

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of how `<fieldset><legend>` does this exact "cut-out" of border.

```css
.hero-banner {
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/Ft1XsIn.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.hero-banner h1 {
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 200px;
}

.hero-banner>fieldset {
  margin: 70px;
  height: 30vh;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}

.hero-banner>fieldset>legend {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero-banner">
  <fieldset>
    <legend><img src="http://www.technozion.org/tz15/assets/mat/images/generic-logo.png" /></legend>
    <h1><small>The Story of</small><br/>This House</h1>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

You may need to adjust the numbers, but this should work with minimal fiddling.

Comment: Although this works, you must keep in mind that it is semantically incorrect and akin to using a table for layout purposes

Comment: @Pete I agree, however as far as I'm aware there is no other way to get this cut-out effect. That is, without turning it into `<div>` soup.

Comment: I would say that with all these new eu laws and more disabled people actually suing people for inaccessible things, I would prefer the div soup 
 - couple of extra styles on one div isn't really that thick a broth :)

Answer (score 1):

I hope that's what you want

```css
.hero-banner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40vw;
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/Ft1XsIn.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #ccc
}
.hero-banner h1 {
  color:#fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 200px;
}
.hero-banner h1 small {}
.border {
  position: absolute;
  top: 70px;
  right: 70px;
  bottom: 70px;
  left: 70px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-top: 0;
}

.top-left {
  border-top: 1px solid #fff;
  width: calc(100% - 400px);
}

.top-right {
  border-top: 1px solid #fff;
  width: 50px;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.hero-banner::before {
  content:url('http://www.technozion.org/tz15/assets/mat/images/generic-logo.png');
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 150px;
  height: 122px;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero-banner">
  <div class="border">
    <div class="top-left"></div>
    <div class="top-right"></div>
  </div>
  <h1><small>The Story of</small><br/>This House</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As per my comment I would use an after and before element - below I have added a box div and styled that

```css
.hero-banner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40vw;
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/Ft1XsIn.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-color: blue;      /* for my test as imiur is blocked */
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.hero-banner h1 {
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 200px;
}

.box {
  position: absolute;
  /* use rgba colour for opacity */
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  border-top: 0;
  top: 40px;
  left: 40px;
  bottom: 40px;
  right: 40px;
}

.box:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: calc(100% - 100px);
  /* the minus number is where you want it to stop from the right */
}

.box:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 450px;  /* width of logo plus amount of space on right */
}

.hero-banner::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 150px;
  height: 122px;
  width: 300px;
  background: url('http://www.technozion.org/tz15/assets/mat/images/generic-logo.png') left top no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero-banner">
  <div class="box">
    <h1><small>The Story of</small><br/>This House</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.logo-container {
  top: 3.2em;
  right: 8em;
}

.p-ltrb-5 {
  left: 5em;
  top: 5em;
  right: 5em;
  bottom: 5em;
}

.outline {
  border-left: 1px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  border-right: 1px solid #fff;
}

.outline:before,
.outline:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 1px;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
}

.outline:before {
  left: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #fff;
  border-right: 30px solid #fff;
  width: 80%
}

.outline:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 1px;
  right: 0;
  border-right: 30px solid #fff;
  width: 2%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col p-0 position-relative">
      <div class="position-absolute  p-ltrb-5">
        <div class="h-100 w-10 outline">

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="position-absolute bg-primary  logo-container">
        <div class="h-100 px-5 py-3 w-100">
          Logo
        </div>
      </div>
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f0/Brooklyn_Bridge_Postdlf.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```